# How to unlock User account on windows 7 home premium?

Tags: windows-7

seeking for help here. I can't access my computer because the password is always Incorrect and I never changed the password.The account is at "User" ,we already did the safe mode with command prompt but still it goes to the windows and required a password.The command prompt too is nowhere to found.Please please i need your help

Comment: If you don't know the password you are not supposed to access the computer. That's the main principle of passwords. You might try to remember / enter it correctly. How the issue started? Were you unable to enter it correctly all of a sudden (maybe mum lock / caps lock is on, Faulty keyboard)? Did it started asking for the password just now?...